# The SailsJS way of connecting to an API. What's the best method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, sails.js, sails.io.js

I'm currently trying to connect to the [Artsy public API](https://developers.artsy.net) and I'm having some trouble. Please go easy on me, I'm new to NodeJS and SailsJS. I've created a file called api/services/Artsy.js and now I'm hung up on whether my approach (see below) is really the Sails way of doing things. That's one question. If not, what is the proper way to set up a basic call to an API in SailsJS? Or more specifically, to the Artsy API?

Issues that come to mind:

- I need to wait until the token is retrieved before I can call an API method that requires it. Is this done via pubsub, or some other technique. Are there any practical examples that show how this works in SailsJS?
- Can you use service calls inside of views? How? Does this even make sense? It seems like it might be useful for an API call.

Note: I've set up the file config/artsy.js that holds important variables. (see this below)

/api/services/Artsy.js

```js
/**
*
* Artsy.js => in api/services
* @description A service that connects to the Artsy.net public API.
* @url https://developers.artsy.net/
**/
var request = require('superagent'),
  traverson = require('traverson'),
  xappToken;

module.exports = {
 
 init: function(){

  sails.log.info('----- Artsy API Initialized -----');

  var clientID = sails.config.artsy.clientId,
      clientSecret = sails.config.artsy.clientSecret,
      apiTokenUrl = sails.config.artsy.apiTokenUrl;

  try{ 

   request
    .post(apiTokenUrl)
    .send({ client_id: clientID, client_secret: clientSecret })
    .end(function(res) {
     if (res) {
      xappToken = res.body.token; 
     } else {
      sails.log.error('api/services/Artsy.js:');
      sails.log.error(res.text);
     }
    });

  } catch(e) {

   sails.log.error('api/services/Artsy.js:');
   sails.log.error(e);

  }
 },

 getArtistStatement: function(){
  
  var api = traverson.jsonHal.from(sails.config.artsy.apiUrl);

  var request = api.newRequest()
   .follow('artist')
   .withRequestOptions({
    headers: {
     'X-Xapp-Token': xappToken,
     'Accept': 'application/vnd.artsy-v2+json'
    }
   })
   .withTemplateParameters({ id: 'andy-warhol' })
   .getResource(function(error, andyWarhol) {
    console.log(andyWarhol.name + 'was born in ' + andyWarhol.birthday + ' in ' + andyWarhol.hometown);
   });
 }

};
```

/config/artsy.js

```js
/**
* artsy.js
*
* @description :: This is the brains that allow the app to connect to artsy.
* @docs        :: http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models
*/
module.exports.artsy = {
  clientId: 'CLIENT_ID',
  clientSecret: 'CLIENT_SECRET',
  apiUrl: 'https://api.artsy.net/api',
  apiTokenUrl: 'https://api.artsy.net/api/tokens/xapp_token'
};
```

Comment: In angular, we'd set the Token to rootScope/Global Var on login/auth, then create a service that sends that in the header of every API request. Probably not relevant but I figured I'd share. You can also store the token in localStorage and call it when needed.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "set the Token to rootScope/Global Var on login/auth"? Have an example that shows this? I believe that I understand what you're saying, I just would like to see it applied.

Comment: Heres an example. On success of login, fire off `Session.create( data )` and pass in the return user object. Here's the Session service that sets the user object in local storage and gives some params. http://pastebin.com/NvHNwedp In your API request using `$http` or whatever, you can pass in the authToken by using `headers = { "AUTHORIZATION": "Token " + Session.get.authToken() };`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your questions correctly so

> That's one question. If not, what is the proper way to set up a basic call to an API in SailsJS?

Service is quite right place for such case. 
And you can call your init method in config/bootstrap.js, or when user has log in or somewhere else.

> I need to wait until the token is retrieved before I can call an API method that requires it. Is this done via pubsub

Yes, you can use pubsub, but it seems better to use promises. For example you can use this lib
https://github.com/istavros/vowjs

> Can you use service calls inside of views? How? Does this even make sense? It seems like it might be useful for an API call.

I think yes, but it seems you should not want it. It looks betted when templates works with controller passed data and nothing else. So use service in controller (or mb model) an then pass results to template.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I believe you may be right, promises seem like the way to go. I've been poking around and it seems like [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) has gotten the attention of the SailsJS community. So I think I'll start there.